# SQL query to use results of two other queries?

Tags: php, mysql, select, drupal-7

I have two queries to get the data like OLD and NEW values from a Table. Here "item1" is the column from which i retrieve the "old" & "new" values.

now, with the result set Query1 & Query2 , i want to check the Second table for the fields "itemOLD" and "itemNEW" to check with the qbove two queries results. Like with Query1 results i will look on itemOLD `AND` the Query 2 with itemNEW. with both in the same row, i want to retrieve the results.

### EDIT1

Data in the TABLE

```
  dbitem TABLE

    id1     id2     item1   
    ------------------------
    1       11      obj1    
    2       22      obj2    
    3       33      obj3    
    4       44      obj4    


   dbcateg TABLE

    id      itemOLD   itemNEW
    --------------------------
    9       obj3      obj1
    8       obj4      obj1
    7       obj1      obj3
    6       obj1      obj4

   RESULT 
   ---------

   Query 1 : set of OLD items from dbitem TABLE
                item1
               -------
                obj1
                obj2

   Query 2 : set of NEW items from dbitem TABLE
                item1
               -------
                obj3
                obj4


   MainQuery: from dbcateg TABLE

        dbcateg.id  dbcateg.itemOLD    dbcateg.NEW
        -------------------------------------------
         7              obj1           obj3 
         6              obj1           obj4
```

Comment: many mistakes i made and not even a comment! ok,,,let the leader comes

Comment: Probably more simple will be create one MySQL query for this? For example try use `IN` operator and sub select: `db_query("
 SELECT dbcateg.item1,dbcateg.item2 
 from dbcateg 
 WHERE dbcateg.item1 IN (SELECT dbitem.item1,dbitem.item2 from dbitem)
);`

Comment: thanks for the comment..please let me think on this..

Comment: @stepozer : but i want the tworesults separately to query them again for the check in  'dbcateg' table . Like this `first = "select the item from db'; second = "select the item from db" ; the_final= select the items from newDb where newDb.first ="first" AND newDb.second = "second"`

Comment: what about: `select the items 
from newDb where newDb.first IN (select the item from db) 
AND newDb.second IN (select the item from db)` how i undersand it must work for you

Comment: @stepozer : thanks  When i worked on it, i found this issue.  the IN can handle only one item right? if i want more than two is there any other way. or else i have to adjust the situation then...:(

Comment: `select the items from newDb where newDb.first IN (select the item1,id from db) AND newDb.second IN (select the item1,id from db)`...will this work

Comment: Now I understand what you want. My query will not work in this case... Can you show real DB structure? Probably we can try solve it use JOIN

Comment: @stepozer : i edited the whole data in the simplest way possible. can you help this to solve!

Comment: Can you take a step back and describe the two tables involved, with some sample data for each, and describe what you are ultimately looking for in a result set.

Comment: @MikeBrant : can u please look at the EDIT 2 section.. just read that, it has all data i think

Comment: That has table description (kind of), but not example of what data looks like in tables for us to understand how the tables may relate.  It would also be extremely helpful if you can give example of what you want the end result set to actually look like.  My guess is you can get what you want in a single query, but we don't know what you want yet to give direction.

Comment: @MikeBrant : ok... so data is important here?.. pls reply..i will poulate that also in a meaningful way.

Comment: @MikeBrant : pls have a look at EDIT3 ; i think its correct pls check

Comment: It is still not clear how you get that result set, as your data in a given column has different formats.  How are the tables related?  What is the criteria for selecting rows into the result set? The essence of the problem here is that you have given no explanation as to the real world meaning of your tables or the relation between them.

Comment: @MikeBrant : thanks , i editted the data now...as OLD and NEW..to retrieve rows with which is transfered from OLD to NEW..pls have a look on it

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for (your queries combined):

```
SELECT dbcateg.id, dbcateg.item2 
FROM dbitem 
INNER JOIN dbcateg on 
(dbitem.item1 = dbcateg.item1 OR dbitem.item1 = dbcateg.item2) AND 
(dbitem.item2 = dbcateg.id1 OR dbitem.item2 = dbcateg.id2)
```

Comment: thanks for the query, but iam getting "zero results returned'

Comment: just now only i could add the data..please have alook on it and guide me

Comment: how do you know which ones are old items and which ones are new items? why do you get only category 7 and 6?

Comment: its through the QUery1 & Query2  `WHERE` condition. I filter out what i need from the    `dbcateg TABLE`

Comment: add the queries on your question. If you also put your example on http://sqlfiddle.com/, that would help a lot.